# Test Webforms Masterpages with Mobile browsers

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, webforms

What is a good way to test a Webforms website with a mobile master page from code?  Electric Mobile Studio works but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome DevTools (Ctrl+Shift+I). 
From DevTools you can toggle device tool bar (Ctrl+Shift+M). 
Once open you can view as different:

- devices
- resolutions
- network speeds
- and change from portrait to landscape.

Comment: I will have to try that.  A more "virtual-machine-look" is what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have been able to find in the past year+

Chrome has an extension called "User-Agent Switcher for Chrome."  It can be used to switch to iPad and other views that will invoke the mobile master page.

The main strength of this solution (for me) is that it can be used from code in debug mode.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg